# Apply changes without closing dialogue?

Tags: gimp

How (if at all), do I apply changes (such as color selection on text) without closing the dialog to see the change?  It's pretty standard UI to have "Apply" as well as "OK" and "Cancel". Is there some hidden way to do this?